# How to get rid of dark border around the selected cell but not the row background colorification?

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, styles

I've applied *False* to the property *IsHitTestVisible* of **all** my cells in the grid. My aim was to get rid of the black, thick border around the clicked cell, as shown with red mark below.

[image]

The problem is that, while the border is gone now, so is the marking of the row. I only wish to get rid of the border, as it's of no relevance which cell that is clicked but of high interest on which row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding style to your `DataGridCell`

```
 <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
 </Style>
```